# Can't access properties of returned objects?

Tags: objective-c

```
//SomeObject.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface SomeObject : NSObject {

}
@property NSInteger aProperty;
@end

//main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SomeObject.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setObject:[[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"key1"];
    [dictionary setObject:[[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"key2"];
    [dictionary objectForKey:@"key1"].aProperty = 5; //Error HERE
    [dictionary release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

But on that line XCode gives me these errors:

```
error: Semantic Issue: Member reference type 'struct objc_object *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'?
error: Semantic Issue: No member named 'aProperty' in 'struct objc_object'
```

Can't I access a property of a returned object? (I mean, without directly calling the setter method)

Comment: char with pointer "*"? I am noob but I never saw char with asterisk with it, like you did "char * argv[]"

Comment: It's like writing char argv[][] or char **argv...it's a bidimesional array, every standard C main receiving command line arguments should have such an argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the returned object:

```
((SomeObject*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"key1"]).aProperty = 5;
```

or:

```
[(SomeObject*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"key1"] setAProperty: 5];
```

or:

```
SomeObject* obj = [dictionary objectForKey:@"key1"];
obj.aProperty = 5;
```

Comment: Still thinking that I wouldn't have to do this in C++...thanks however!

Comment: Wait a moment, solution 1 should be `((SomeObject*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"key1"]).aProperty = 5;`